# How to Hide Left Panel of Yahoo Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I would like to hide the left panel of Yahoo Mail which normally contains Inbox, Draft, Sent, Folders, etc. in order to enjoy of a larger working space. Notice that I need to toggle its visibility but don't like to hide it permanently.

P.S. I am not referring to hiding the user-defined folders; I am referring to the whole left panel including Compose and Inbox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not possible in the latest version. It was possible to show/hide it in the previous version, but with the latest update (March 2014?), that option got yanked. It’s possible you might find a Greasemonkey (or Userscripts) script, but I’m not aware of any.

Comment: I am using FireFox by which through Developers functions I can find the the mentioned panel in the pertaining CSS; however I don't know how to assign a hotkey to toggle its visibility.